# Zero point five gram or half a gram?

Tags: numbers

I understand you should write out figures in words at the beginning of a sentence. So what happens when you have a decimal number - for example: "0.5 g of shoots and roots is required for the sample."

Edit: No, not how to say it. How to write it in an academic paper.

Comment: So what, you're asking how to *say* it? However you like, as long as it makes sense...

Comment: Haven't you solved your problem with "Half a gram"?

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing decimal fractions spelled out.  If they happen to correspond with a fraction word, like half, quarter, third, etc., that word might be substituted.  But I have always seen decimal values expressed only as numbers.

Comment: Agreed, @fixer1234, especially for an academic paper.

Comment: Questions about academic writing style might be accepted at [academia.se] or [writers.se]. More information at their respective help centers.

Answer (score 5):

The Chicago Manual of Style (13th ed) agrees that

> At the beginning of a sentence any number that would ordinarily be set in figures is spelled out... (section 8.9)

It also says

> If this is impracticable or cumbersome, the sentence should be recast so that it does not begin with a number. (section 8.10)

I might recast the OP's sentence as:

> The sample requires 0.5 g of shoots and roots.